# Sorting Vector of Coordinates C++

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, copying

I am trying to sort a vector of coordinates. The vector has pointers to these coordinates. I want to sort them by x and by y. What I am currently thinking of how to do this is as follows make two copies of the vector and then sort them. I am unsure of the following two things:
1) How to make a copy of a vector of pointers
2) How to sort both the points by x and y in the vectors and ensure also that they are properly sorted as follows (1,4),(1,5)

I have been reading and trying to figure out if there were any built in functions but I am not sure if for example **sort function** would correctly sort the x and y properly orderwise.

Here is what I have so far and any help would be appreciated.

```
typedef struct{double x; double y;) pt;
vector<pt*>v1;
vector<pt*>*v2 = v1;
// allocate memory for the points and push_back on the vector
the vector would have the following points {(1,7),(4,4),(1,3),(-2,4)}
```

When sorted it for x, it would be 
X={(-2,4),(1,3),(1,7),(4,4)} and
Y={(1,3),(-2,4),(4,4),(1,7)}

---

UPDATE:

I am currently at this stage but it is still not working... :(

```
bool compare(pt* m1, pt* m2){return(m1->x <= m2->x) && (m1->y <= m2->y);}

vector<pt*>v1_x = v1;
sort(v1_x.begin(), v1_x.end(), comparer);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly easy using a custom comparator to do the dereferencing, as well as ready-made lexicographic tuple comparison:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

struct pt { double x, double y };

std::vector<pt*> v = /* ... */ ;

auto x = v, y = v;   // copies

std::sort(x.begin(), x.end(),
          [](pt * a, pt * b) -> bool
          { return std::tie(a->x, a->y) < std::tie(b->x, b->y); });

std::sort(y.begin(), y.end(),
          [](pt * a, pt * b) -> bool
          { return std::tie(a->y, a->x) < std::tie(b->y, b->x); });
```

Of course the objects pointed to by the pointers must live at least as long as you're using the pointers in `v`, `x` and `y`.

Comment: is it really as simple as that?

Comment: @Masterminder: Modulo getting all the ownership semantics right, sure, why not.

Comment: So once I make the copy of the vector, the sort will acutally do that for me if I specify the tie part? Like will it actually rearrange the pointers?

Comment: The `x` and `y` vectors will be sorted according to the specified lexicographic ordering. The original vector `v` will be untouched.

Comment: Is there anyway that this could be rewritten? I get a few error messages and am trying to fix them but my compiler is complaining about it not having library support and that it is currently experimental. Also it says I should have a primary-expression before the []

Comment: @Masterminder: you need C++11 for the lambdas (add `-std=c++0x` to GCC and Clang, for example). You can always rewrite the lambda as a standalone function, though. As for `tie`, you could manually make a pair of references, since `pair` also implements lexicographic comparison, or just spell out the comparison by hand.